# Showing $\forall x(p(x) \land \lnot p(f(x)))$ is unsatisfiable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Showing $\forall x(p(x) \land \lnot p(f(x)))$ is unsatisfiable.

So i want to use resolution . The clauses are $\{p(x)\}\ \{p(f(x))\}$ . Obviously i cannot use resolution because they use the same variable. So i have to swap out $x$ and turn it to $y$. Then i have the clauses

$\{p(y)\}\ \{p(x)\}\ \{p(f(x))\}$.

By resolving first and third clause with substitution $y/f(x)$ i get the empty clause and showed that it is unsatisfiable.

My question is, is what im saying correct and why am i allowed to swap the $x$ in $p(x)$ with a $y$. When finding the most  general unifier this step is not allowed. Why is this allowed in resolution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$\{\}$` for $\{\}$.

Comment: ok, i will thank you.

Comment: But if the universe of discourse is empty then the statement is vacuously true.  I'm assuming the first-order logic system you're using somehow forbids that case?

Comment: Yes we assume that there is at least one element in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that variables are just 'dummy' placeholders, and so can be replaced by any other variable, as you just did in your problem.

However, when unifying with a clause that contains multiple different variables, you don't want to replace those different variables with the same variable (e.g. you don't want to replace both $X$'s and $Y$'s with $Z$'s, or just replace the $X$'s with $Y$'s when you already have a bunch of $Y$'s), because now you are effectively saying that you need to use the same object for all those variables, and thereby unnecessarily restricting the possibilities .. meaning that you don't end up using the most general unifier.

But in your particular example you only have $1$ variable in your clause, and you can replace that $1$ variable with *any* other variable without losing any kind of generality.

Comment: excuse me its not very intuitive to me . What is happening when i replace the variable in resolution.? $\forall x p(x) \land \lnot p(f(x))) $ becomes $\forall y p(y) \land \lnot p(f(y)))$? What also happens when im unifying clauses. What happens to the $\forall x$ ?

Comment: @asddf That particular replacement of variables is with regard to a whole statements, not a clause.  Which is just fine, by the way, and the same kind of thinking applies: all variables are dummies, so you can always replace them with other variables: those two statements you mention here are indeed equivalent, and so this is something you can do.  But you can also replace variables during resolution ... again, the only thing you want to avoid is to replace different variables with the same variable inside a single clause, unless that is forced by the unification.

Comment: So when im adding a clause such as $p(y)$ am i infact doing $\forall x \forall y p(x) \land \lnot p(f(x)) \land p(y)$ ??

Comment: What is actually bothering me is, why can i change the x from one clause to another variable without changing the x in the other clause ?. Is it because $\forall x p(x) \land \lnot p(f(x)) \equiv \forall x p(x) \land \forall x \lnot p(f(x))$ ???

Comment: @asddf Ah, I see what you're asking ... and yes, you answered it yourself!  You get two separate clauses here, and you can change variables in one without changing them in any opthers ... the fact that they came from the same original statement does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

If $\forall x~(p(x)\wedge\neg p(f(x))$, then $\forall x~p(x)$ and $\forall x~\neg p(f(x))$.

You express this as $\{p(x)\wedge\neg p(f(x))\}$ infers $\{p(x)\}, \{\neg p(f(x))\}$, for arbitrary values of $x$.

But if $\forall x~p(x)$ then $\forall x~p(f(x))$, which is to say: if the predicate holds for any value at all, then it holds for any value returned by the function.   So if $\{p(x)\}$ then $\{p(x)\}[x\backslash f(x)]$, or simply $\{p(f(x)\}$, holds.

So $\{p(x)\},\{\neg p(f(x))\}$ are contradictory, and we conclude that the statement cannot be satisfied.